# Android is creating multiple instances of my service

Tags: android, service

In my Android app I want to be able to play some audio in the background. I figured using a MediaPlayer in a service should be just what I need. So I created a service pretty much following Google's example code on the Android developer website. However, my problem is that whenever a new activity is started that tries to bind to the service, a new service is started (or at least onCreate is being re-called). I've read through the docs and what I'm doing *should* be completely legal. Can anyone provide some further insight? Thanks!

```
public class PlayerService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener {

public class PlayerBinder extends Binder {
    PlayerService getService() {
        return PlayerService.this;
    }
}

private final IBinder mBinder = new PlayerBinder();

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}
```

and from my activity I bind to a service from `onCreate`

```
private void doBindService() {
    this.bindService(new Intent(this, PlayerService.class), connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `bindService` your `Service` is created and tied to the lifecycle of your `Activity`. That means when your `Activity` is destroyed, so is your `Service`.

If you want your `Service` to remain started you must first call `startService(Intent)`. You could for example call this in your applications `onCreate()`.

After that, you can still bind to your `Service` and when you unbind it will remain started until Android decides to kill your process or if you call `stopService(Intent)` or `stopSelf()` from somewhere in your code.

For better results, and having uninterrupted music playback you should set your `Service` to run in foreground mode (see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29)).

Keep in mind that it will STILL be possible for Android to kill your process and stop the music playback, but if you are in foreground mode the chances are very very slim.